# Can't install DeepDive

Tags: openssl, anaconda, libssl

I am trying to install [DeepDive](http://deepdive.stanford.edu/installation) but I am getting this error on my terminal:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/lukedinh/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
 Reason: image not found
```

I'm on macOS 10.14.2 Mojave. I have updated openssl and homebrew to the latest versions. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Note that you will need to redo the last symlink again if you update versions of OpenSSL beyond 1.0.2q.